# How to view files in a library in SharePoint Designer

Tags: sharepoint-designer, file, sharepoint-library

I am not able to view sharepoint library files in SP Designer. Please help me in this regard.[image: screensot attached]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open site in designer->All Files-> select Document Library
please check the below image

[image: Designerview]

Comment: Please mark my solutions as  answer if it solves  your issue

Comment: all files option is not visible for me, in my SP D 2013 . what may be the reason for this?